# Iterated Ito Integral, Gaussian Volterra Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, pr.probability, martingales

Let me define
$$
 J^f_{n}(t) =  \, \int_0^t \int_0^{t_1} \ldots \int_0^{t_{n-1}} f(t, t_1, \ldots, t_n) \; dB_{t_n} ...dB_{t_1}
$$
where $f:[0,1]^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nice deterministic function. Note that the upper limit of the outer integral appears in the integrand. I would like an estimate on the tail of $\sup_{t \in (0,1]} |J^f_n(t)|$ i.e.
$$ 
\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in (0,1]} |J^f_n(t)| \geq K\right) \leq \; ?
$$ 
Note that we can write $J^f_n(t)$ in the following form
$$
J^f_n(t) = \int_0^t J^f_{n-1}(t,t_1) \; dB_{t_1}
$$
which is precisely the form of a Gaussian Volterra process (see e.g. http://www.infres.enst.fr/~decreuse/recherche/volterra.pdf ) except here we have a *stochastic* kernel.

- **Has anyone encountered a process like this before? Does it have a name?**

---

In the case of a constant integrand, such an estimate is fairly easy to find. For the integrand $f \equiv 1$, I define
$$
I_{n}(t):= J^f_n(t) = \int_0^t \int_0^{t_1} \ldots \int_0^{t_{n-1}} 1 \; dB_{t_n} ...dB_{t_1}
$$
then we can use the martingale inequality (found e.g. in proposition 4.24 here statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/StoCal/sc3.pdf )
$$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in (0,T]} |M_t| \geq K_1, \langle M_. \rangle _T \leq K_2\ \right) \leq 2 \exp \left( - \frac{K_1^2}{2K_2} \right) $$
recursively applied to $I_n(t)$, then $I_{n-1}(t)$ etc. to get a bound of the type
$$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in (0,1]} |I_n(t)| \geq K\right) \leq C_n \exp \left( - K^{d_n} \right) $$
with $C_n$ and $d_n$ positive constants.

- The problem for $J^f_n(t)$ is that, in general, it is not a martingale or a Guassian process

**With this in mind, what tools can we use to analyse $J^f_{n}(t)$**

---

If the function $f(t, t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ splits into $f_0(t)f_1(t_1)\ldots f_n(t_n)$ then we can pass each function outside one of the integrals and we are left with a martingale inside so this makes things considerably easier. This motivates the following question

- **Is there a theory for approximating general $f(t, t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ by products of functions $f_0(t) f_1(t_1) \ldots f_n(t_n)$ ?**

Comment: Your $I_n$ is basically a Hermite function, by Ito's classical results on the "multiple Wiener integral". See, e.g. section 5.4.1 of  http://books.google.com/books?id=V2BS_Dmp0XoC 

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reference. It seems iterated/multiple Ito integrals with constant integrand are quite well understood. It is really when the integrand depends on the upper limit that things become harder.

Answer (score 6):

The estimate you are interested in has already been studied. The tail bound

$
\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0,1]} | J_n^f (t)| \ge K \right) \le C_1 \exp( -C_2 K^{2/n})
$

was proved by C. Borell. The main tools are infinite dimensional isoperimetric inequalities. It was later proved by M. Ledoux that we even have

$
\lim_{K \to \infty} \frac{1}{K^{2/n}}\log \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0,1]} | J_n^f (t)| \ge K \right) =-I_n(f)
$

where $I_n(f)$ is known explicitly.

[Michel Ledoux, A note on large deviations for Wiener chaos](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SPS/SPS_1990__24_/SPS_1990__24__1_0/SPS_1990__24__1_0.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://www.math.spbu.ru/diffjournal/EN/numbers/2017.1/article.2.1.html)

Here is my book (385 p) about approximation of multiple Ito and Stratonovich stochastic integrals

Answer (score 0):

http://www.math.spbu.ru/diffjournal/pdf/kuznetsov_book3.pdf

http://www.math.spbu.ru/diffjournal/pdf/kuznetsov_book2.pdf

Here is 2 my books (1000p in Russian and 385p in English) from 2017, where iterated Ito and Stratonovich stochastic integrals approximation is systematically considered by multiple Fourier-Legendre and trigonometric Fourier series. Expansions and exact mean-square errors of approximations is derived for integrals of multiplicity 2,3,4,5. General case (k, k in N) is also considered...
The books are FREE.